# Comoving sound horizon at last scattering

Tags: cosmology, acoustics

I tried to calculate the comoving sound horizon at last scattering using the integral $$r_s=\int_{0}^{380,000}{c_s\cdot (1+z)\ dt}.$$ According to most of the measurements it is approximately $150$ Mpc nevertheless my result is more or less half where $z=1090$ and $c_s=c/(3^{1/2})$, $c=3.076\cdot 10^{-7}$ Mpc. Do I miss something so obvious?

Comment: Thank you Sebastiano

Comment: Its hard to see what you missed without looking what you have tried